# Created a credit memo... can i revert this?

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I had to create a credit memo for an order that was returned. Accidentally I did this for the wrong order.

Can I rectify this?
And how should I do this?

Can I just remove the corresponding line in database in:

- sales_flat_creditmemo
- sales_flat_creditmemo_comment
- sales_flat_creditmemo_grid
- sales_flat_creditmemo_item

I have no stock management in store.

Answer (score 3):

No. Magento does a lot of calculations when you create a creditmemo.

the sales table is changed and the *_canceled columns are filled. Same for order_item and *_refunded column.

IF you really want to do this and I highly disadvise to do so, you could do a dump of the database locally, create a creditmemo and then diff the dump before and after to get a feeling for what changes.

Please read the comment by @Simon!

> I do not think that creating a creditmemo fills any *_canceled column. These are filled when you actually cancel an order.

Not sure about this, so I leave it up to you to check - if you checked on that, PLEASE EDIT THIS POST! :D

Comment: I do not think that creating a creditmemo fills any `*_canceled` column. These are filled when you actually *cancel* an order.